# I want to arrange entire cells in specific column, instead of individual cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I used `POI` and tried to arrange one entire column. But only the way I found is arrange individual cell. Although I found `sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle()` and tried to use this function, it doesn't work at all.
could you let me know the way of using `setDefaultColumnStyle()` or another way.

below code is my code to arrange individual cell.

```
    xlsxFile = new File("data.xlsx");
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

    cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
    row = sheet1.createRow(0);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("name");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

My english skill is a little awkward. Thank you for reading. If there is anything weird, please let me know.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "arrange one entire column".

Comment: it means aligning text in the middle of cell. another expression is aligning horizontal center over the one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an bug in Apache POI. There are two issues:

First: After using `Sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle` with a style which defines alignments, POI does not set `applyAlignment="true"` in the `xf` element's tag in `styles.xml`. But it should, because only that will cause Excel to apply the alignments from that style to new cells.

Second: POI itself does not apply this style to new cells in that column. It should set `s="1"`, where 1 is the style number, in the corresponding `c` tag of `Sheet1.xml`.

So we have to workaround:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class CenteredColumn {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

   Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

   CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
   cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

   sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(1, cellStyle);

   //Workaround 1: We set setApplyAlignment(true) into the `xf` element's tag in styles.xml.
   //This causes Excel applying alignments from this style to new cells in that column.
   for (int i = 0; i < ((XSSFWorkbook)wb).getStylesSource().getNumCellStyles(); i++) {
    if (((XSSFWorkbook)wb).getStylesSource().getStyleAt(i).equals(cellStyle)) {
     ((XSSFWorkbook)wb).getStylesSource().getCellXfAt(i).setApplyAlignment(true);
    }
   }

   Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
   if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(0);

   Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
   if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue("name");
   //Workaround 2: We set the cellStyle to the new cell because POI will not do this itself.
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);

  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could raise a bug in the [Apache POI bugzilla](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI) for this problem, and attach/list your investigations and proposed fix?

Comment: There are similiar bugs already: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51037. I've found that at least Excel 2007 itself is tolerant enough applying the alignment also without `applyAlignment="true"` in styles.xml. Only Libreoffice Calc is not. But Libreoffice is not the goal of POI. So we have to use the showed workaround for that. And for the missing apply of the `DefaultColumnStyle` to new cells in that column in POI, the comment 9 in the linked bug shows clearly that this will not be fixed.