# Java Apache POI: setting default column style doesnt work for existing values

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have the following example code:

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet");
SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("value");

XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
DataFormat fmt = wb.createDataFormat();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, cellStyle);

FileOutputStream out;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream("filename.xlsx");
    try {
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It successfully creates an excel file and puts the value "value" in it (column A, row 1).
I want to set the column style for column A to "@" (=Text) which is working very well but not for the cell with the already existing value "value". All other empty cells in column A are set to the style "@" successfully.
I have to work with SXSSFWorkbook since I am creating huge excel files.

Comment: If a cell already has a value in it, then it already has a style. So, sounds like it's behaving as expected to me!

Comment: I don't really understand that because I tried to set the style before and after setting the value. The result is the same. If it is not possible to set style on columns with values why the functionality does exist at all? As soon as a value is set the style is lost.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463072/i-want-to-arrange-entire-cells-in-specific-column-instead-of-individual-cells/34469637#34469637. POI itself does not apply the DefaultColumnStyle to new cells in that column. It should set s="1", where 1 is the style number, in the corresponding c tag of Sheet1.xml.

Comment: Seems that it is only possible to set the style on the cell level if you want to have the style AND the value. I will use the proposed workaround in the suggested post.

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you just set the cell style before insertinr the value?